# How to validate a SHA256 signed result with a public key

Tags: c#, validation, rsa, sha256

I need to validate a user by using an external authorize API. This API requires me to send a SHA-256 hash of something unique on my client side. I should use this to validate the signature later on.

I'm generating the Hash like this. As text I'm sending a unique Session ID:

```
private static string CalculateSHA256Hash(string text)
{
    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] hashValue;
    byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

    SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();
    string hex = "";

    hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);

    foreach (byte x in hashValue)
    {
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
    }

    return hex;
}
```

From the API I received a public signing key as a string:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA185vTa2xheB 
<..>
SLhDuNk0SkiL7f8KbOG3tP9IDmAcAfoZWw/o2XjUxVLp1uw9V/hj4oJoapyS2sW4
cwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I should use this key somehow to validate the response. The response I receive is this 512 character long string:

```
"57ec50faf72340f9618cf690160ab6b251a2d76fcce61583779804a07f8ac1f520bf09a4f5918a3
<...>
245f8d00b2cce3fa1ecc849f8771be0c8"
```

Now I should be able to Validate the signature I've received with the Public-key-string and my own hashed value.

How do I do this?

**Edit**

The hasing & padding scheme used on the API is "SHA256_RSA_PKCS_PSS"

Comment: Does the documentation of the API not specify how to do this? I'm guessing the public key contains your session id encrypted somehow. I don't **think** there is a standard method of doing this. It will depend on the implementation of the API.

Comment: It says: The 32 byte SHA256 data (what I'm sending) is going to be signed. The 512 character result string is the signature which is put over the data. I should be able to validate this signature with the public key string.